# Running testng.xml from Command line always returns "Total tests run : 0"

Tags: command-line, automated-tests, appium, testng-eclipse

I encountered a problem when trying to run testng.xml fro command line as it automatically returns: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v7kSt.png)

If i run testng.xml from eclipse(ProjectName->testng.xml->rightClick->Run as->TestNG suite) all works ok:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GArk2.png)
The code from the class is:`

```
package TestNGZ;

import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;

import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;


import org.openqa.selenium.By;

import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
import org.testng.Assert;

import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class ClassOne {
  
AndroidDriver dr;
    
    @Test
    public void call() throws MalformedURLException{
        
        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
        capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "Nexus5");
        capabilities.setCapability("platformVersion", "6.0");
        capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
        capabilities.setCapability("appPackage", "com.age.wgg.appspot");
        capabilities.setCapability("appActivity", "com.age.wgg.appspot.Main");
        
        dr = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);
    }
    @Test
    public void login() throws InterruptedException {
        
        String buttonCheckLogIn = "Settings";
        
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(dr,30);
        
        //Implicit Wait
    //  dr.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(1,TimeUnit.SECONDS); 
        
        //Explicit Wait
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//android.widget.Button[5]")));
        //Tap on FB Login 
        dr.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.Button[5]")).click();
        
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//android.widget.EditText[1]")));
        
        //Insert Username 
        dr.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.EditText[1]")).click();
        dr.getKeyboard().sendKeys("waaionel@yahoo.ro");
        //Insert Password
        dr.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.EditText[2]")).click();
        dr.getKeyboard().sendKeys("Gameloft2013");
        //Tap on Log In button
        dr.findElementByAccessibilityId("Log In ").click();
        
        
        //Explicit Wait
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//android.view.View")));
        //Tap OK in Confirmation Prompt
        dr.findElementByAccessibilityId("OK ").click();

        //Explicit Wait
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//android.widget.Button[5]")));
        
        //Verification if the Login was successfully or not
        if (dr.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.Button[5]")).getText().equals(buttonCheckLogIn)) {
            System.out.println("Log In ===> Success");
        } else {
        System.out.println("Log In ===> Failed");
        
        }
    }
    
    @Test
    public void logout() throws InterruptedException {
        
        String buttonCheckLogOut = "Log in";
        
        //Verifying FB Log out functionality 
        dr.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.Button[5]")).click();
        dr.findElement(By.name("Logout")).click();
        dr.findElement(By.name("YES")).click();
        
        Assert.assertTrue(dr.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.Button[5]")).getText().equals(buttonCheckLogOut));
        //Verification if the Log out was successfully or not
        if (dr.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.Button[5]")).getText().equals(buttonCheckLogOut)) {
            System.out.println("Log Out ===> Success");
        } else {
        System.out.println("Log Out ===> Failed");
        
        }
    
        //Kill Session
        dr.quit();
    }
}`
```

In Command Line I execute the following command:

```
  java -cp "C:\Users\Ionut B\Downloads\eclipse-java-kepler-SR1-win32-x86_64\eclipse\plugins\org.testng.eclipse_6.11.0.201703011520\lib\*;C:\Users\Ionut B\workspace\TestZero\bin" org.testng.TestNG testng.xml
```

Appium server is running, Emulator is on.
I have searched all over but i did not find a solution to this and maybe somebody from here can help me .
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I found what was wrong.
In the path to the libs "...\lib*" it must be all .JAR that were used also in Eclipse, in this particular case the path was only to testng.jar, so in the Projects folder I made a lib folder with all Jar files used in Eclipse.
Thanks.